# PHP class array question

Tags: php, arrays, class

For some reason my array I am returning is not what I expect. Could someone explain to me why I am getting the current results, and what I can do to fix it? Here is the code in question:

```
public static function getProduct($_row, $_value)
{
  $stmt = _DB::init()->prepare("SELECT pid, name, quantity, price, cost 
                                FROM products
                                WHERE $_row = ?"
                              );                            
  if($stmt->execute(array($_value))) 
  {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
      return $row;
  }          
}

  $product = Class::getProduct('pid',1);
  print_r($product);
```

When I print the following array I am getting two results per row like so:

```
Array ( [pid] => 1 [0] => 1 [name] => Boondoggle [1] => Boondoggle [quantity] => 12 [2] => 12 [price] => 9.9900 [3] => 9.9900 [cost] => 12.9900 [4] => 12.9900 ) Boondoggle
```

I was only wanting to show the associative results. What is wrong with my function?

Comment: What interface do you use to connect to DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it you are using PDO to communicate with your DBMS. The PDOStatement::fetch() method's first argument is a parameter to tell it what to return. By default it returns each column in both name format and numbered index format to allow iterating through columns easier. To just get the column names as indexes, you can pass it PDO::FETCH_ASSOC to your call. So the fetch statement would look like this:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

See here for more details:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 1):

Pass PDO::FETCH_ASSOC to your fetch call:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

edit: I'm just assuming you're using PDO, of course